# database not startup, but listener yes with oracle 12 with centos

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to configure database startup at boot (oracle 12 with CentOs).
I've created a new service like that:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/oracle-rdbms.service
# Invoking Oracle scripts to start/shutdown Instances defined in /etc/oratab
# and starts Listener
[Unit]
Description=Oracle Database(s) and Listener
Requires=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
ExecStart=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbstart /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 &
ExecStop=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbshut /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 &
User=oracle
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I see listener up and running:

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-APR-2020 10:35:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle19.dummy.es)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                01-APR-2020 10:27:54
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 7 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle19/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle19.dummy.es)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

but database is not mounted. I must do startup to mount.
How could I do to mount at boot the database?
--EDIT

My oratab

```
 more /etc/oratab
#



# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by either Database Configuration Assistant while creating
# a database or ASM Configuration Assistant while creating ASM instance.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third field indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
controlm:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1:N
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post contents of `/etc/oratab` and `$ORACLE_HOME/startup.log`

Comment: I put in main post oratab. Startup.log I don't have because the service not startup the database

Comment: First you must replace 'N' by 'Y'  in `/etc/oratab` to make dbstart to start the database instance. What is the exact version of Oracle ? I'm not sure these scripts are OK with Oracle 12.2.0.1/18c/19c.

Comment: Make sure dbstart and dbstop scripts run as oracle user and not as root user.

Comment: @pifor is right. changing to Y from N in the ```oratab``` should mount the database or at least give you a log output to indicate if you have any additional problems.